# Setup local network on Mac and share it via WiFi, but with no internet connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I want to use my iPhone as remote control for VLC.
I use http://hobbyistsoftware.com/VLC-more and it is working fine when I am connected to my AP.

I will use my MacBook on place where no AP connection will be available (actually even current is not available) for playing videos.

Is it possible and how to run my mac as default gateway and AP but just for local network so that I can connect my iPhone to it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an ad hoc (IBSS) network, just pull down the Wi-Fi Menu Extra to "Create Network…". This is probably all you need. The Mac won't actually be acting as a true AP; it will just be a peer in the ad-hoc network. Also, the Mac won't be acting as a default gateway or DHCP server or anything, but it'll give itself IPv4 and IPv6 link-local (a.k.a. "self assigned") addresses, as will your iPhone. You don't need a DHCP server if all your devices know how to self-assign unique addresses like that, you don't need a default (or otherwise) gateway if you don't need this network to connect to another one.

If you really want your Mac to act as a true AP, default IPv4 gateway (a gateway to nowhere), and DHCP server, then go to `System Preferences > Sharing > Internet Sharing` and choose to share connection "From:" <any interface other than Wi-Fi>, "To computers using:" Wi-Fi.

Comment: for part starting with "If you really want your Mac to act as a true AP, ..." do I need to do "To create an ad hoc (IBSS) network,..." or just this first part ?

Comment: No, turning on Internet Sharing over Wi-Fi automatically puts the radio into AP mode, regardless of whether it was previously in client or IBSS mode.